# Does a server physical location have any negative SEO affects for regional domains?

Tags: seo, dns, location, reverse-proxy

We host about 20 separate web applications and counting, each having atleast one unique top level domain name. Almost all of which are .com.au. We also manage our own DNS name servers. All on Australian soil.

A couple times I have suggested moving our Australian VPS instances to overseas providers namely in the US as they provide much better value for money. We have decent enough caching strategies in place that the increased latency won't be a real issue.

However I'm often met with the response, **"having our servers overseas affects SEO"**. We've since had a major issue that will lead to infrastructure changes and I would like to suggest once again that we move our servers to the US.

**My question is**, is there any weight to this statement? And if so, are there any ways around this affect?

Possible reverse proxying all requests through an Australian server? Just throwing ideas out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it does matter.  Google and other search engines look to provide the most relevant content to searchers, and therefore, if I am in the US, it thinks that I probably don't want to look for information in China or Russia or Australia.  Also you will need to be careful of speeds if you do reverse proxy.  Outside of location based search indexing, Google will lower SEO if loading speeds are too high.  If that is the route you take then I would suggest using a CDN within or near Australia to serve any static files, like JS CSS and images, which will reduce page speeds.

Comment: We use a series of CDN where possible, and we do host a local CDN which I plan to keep. I would think the weight of .com.au would out rank the server's locations as it is common place for servers to be located off shore. Regarding the speed affecting rank, Google has stated the affect this will have on a site is negligible if the have good SEO practices. But I agree, reverse proxy isn't the greatest idea for speed, but it gives us a great failover which is what we are in desperate need of.

Comment: I understand completely where you are at brother (or sister).  I am working on overhauling my companies hosting strategy before our infrastructure collapses on itself, and it is a massive headache of finding the time and the finances, but before doing anything always do your research on what you plan and make sure that every angle is covered.